# Prove the inequality $\int^{3}_{-3}\left|f(t) \right|dt\leq \sqrt{6} \left( \int^{3}_{-3}\left|f(t) \right|^2dt \right) ^{1/2}$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis

I want to prove the inequality

\begin{align} \int^{3}_{-3}\left|f(t) \right|dt\leq \sqrt{6} \left( \int^{3}_{-3}\left|f(t) \right|^2dt \right) ^{1/2}\end{align}

Actually, I don't know where to start. However, does it have anything to with the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality for Integrals? Please, I need your help!

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz should work if you work with $1\cdot |f(t)|$.

Comment: $
\sqrt{6}=\left(\int_{-3}^31^2\ dt\right)^{1/2}
$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the Cauchy-Schwarz says that $\int|fg|dx \le \sqrt{\int |f|^2dx\int|g|^2dx}$. Consider $g=\mathbf 1_\Omega$, where
$$
\mathbf 1_\Omega(x):=\begin{cases}1 &; x\in\Omega \\
0 &;x\ne \Omega.
\end{cases}
$$
Here you have $\Omega=[-3,3]$. Can you finish the proof?